# Wordpress REST API V2 return 300 posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get a list of all posts on the site REST API, but I only get back 10:

```
axios.get('wp-json/wp/v2/posts?custom_per_page=300')
```

```
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', 'change_post_per_page', 10, 2 );

 function change_post_per_page( $args, $request ) {
    $max = max( (int) $request->get_param( 'custom_per_page' ), 300 );
    $args['posts_per_page'] = $max;    
    return $args;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'rest_post_collection_params', 'custom_per_page', 10, 1 );
function custom_per_page( $params ) {
    if ( isset( $params['per_page']) && !empty($_GET['custom_per_page']) ) {
                $params['per_page']['maximum'] = intval($_GET['per_page']);
    }
    return $params;
}
```

```js
axios.get('/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=200&custom_per_page=true');
```

I don't recommend this, because you can overload your server very easily. The best approach would be to use [pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/) and load 100 posts per time.